# Algorithmic complexity of triangularization code

Tags: matlab, time-complexity, linear-algebra

I have the following (partial) code for triangularization of a sparse mxn matrix A ( n is an even number and m=3n/2-2):

```
y=0;
for k=1:n
if(mod(k,2)==0)
    y=y+1;
end
    for j=k+1:n
        A(k,j)=A(k,j)-tau*U(k,k);
        if (k<=n-2)
            for i=n-1:n
                A(i,j)=A(i,j)-tau*U(i,k);
            end
        end
        for i=n+1:n-2+y
            A(i,j)=A(i,j)-tau*U(i,k);
        end            
    end
end
```

And I am interested in finding it's exact algorithmic complexity (in big O notation) as a function of both m and n. I obtained different results due to the if branches.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is off-topic here or not, but wouldn't [CS.StackExchange](http://cs.stackexchange.com) be the appropriate place for this sort of question?

Comment: How is `m` used in the code? And `y` starts at 0?

Comment: Yes, y starts at 0, sorry about that. m is not used in the code because his value is a function of n: m=3n/2-2. m affects the code in the last for (because n-2+y=m at the last iteration)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
y=0;
// n times
for k=1:n
    // some constant complexity stuff
    // it basically sets y to floor(k/2)
    if(mod(k,2)==0)
        y=y+1;
    end
    // n-k times
    for j=k+1:n
        A(k,j)=A(k,j)-tau*U(k,k);
        // executed everytime except the last few iteration of the outermost loop
        if (k<=n-2)
            // constant complexity
            for i=n-1:n
                A(i,j)=A(i,j)-tau*U(i,k);
            end
        end
        // executes y-2 times
        for i=n+1:n-2+y
            // so we basically need to bound the number of times this is executed
            A(i,j)=A(i,j)-tau*U(i,k);
        end            
    end
end
```

In `k`-th iteration the middle loop is iterated `n-k` times and the last innermost loop
iterates `y-2` which is `floor(k/2)-2` times (regardless of `j`)

So the innermost assignment executes `Sum (n - k)(k/2 - 2)` for `k=1:n` times, which is `Θ(n^3)`.